# Localization in WinRT xaml

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

In my metro app using c# and XAML, I need to localize all the strings used in XAML. But I found that it is not similar to the Windows Phone apps. Please suggest me a way to localize all the text used in XAML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward overview of localization, and should address most of your questions.

[Quickstart: Translating UI resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965329%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Why it is different from windows phone?

Comment: @Aneesh I believe it's the same framework that's used in WP8.